# 404 not found assets files in django

Tags: django, path, settings

I don't know why I'm getting this error continuously modifying the routes of my settings.py, I have the tree directory of my project as follows:

```
/dgp
     /assets
         /css
         /js
         ...

     /sales
     manage.py
     /dgp
         settings.py
```

As you can see, I want to access the assets folder which is one folder up to settings.py, in my settings files I have the follow configuration:

```
  PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '..','static'))

  STATIC_URL = '/static/'       

  STATICFILES_DIRS = (
      os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,"..","assets")),     
 )
```

But always I'm getting a 404 error finding assets files:

```
  "GET /static/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1688
```

I don't know why it's concatenating /static with /assets but I prove hard-coding with absolute pahts and neither... I don't know what's wrong... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you referencing the static files in your templates? It looks like you are including `assets/` in that path when you shouldn't be.

For example, if you are using `{% static "assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}` try switching it to `{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}`. If you are using the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` variable within the templates to get the path, you would also just drop the `assets/` part of the path in the same way.